# Why does a CustomFieldSerializer need static methods?

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, gwt-rpc

You use a [`CustomFieldSerializer`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideCustomSerialization)  to define custom serialisation and deserialisation for an object.

It's ostensibly easy to define custom serialization for your class `Xxx`:

- create a class called `Xxx_CustomFieldSerializer` that extends `CustomFieldSerializer<Xxx>`,
- implement abstract methods `serializeInstance` and `deserializeInstance`, and optionally `instantiateInstance`.

This generates a gazillion compile errors that boil down to the following:

```
subtype Custom Field Serializer 'Xxx_CustomFieldSerializer' does not define a deserialize method: 'public static void deserialize(SerializationStreamReader reader,Xxx instance)' (reached via Xxx)'
```

It wants you to create static methods that do exactly what the implemented methods do. Obviously one delegates to the other, but it means you can't extract out all of this boilerplate for similar types `Xxx`.

Why? Is this just left over from an old version of GWT or something? Is there a way to avoid having to write all the extra stuff?

Comment: Could you show your code? It [_should_ work](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=9592). Also, put a breakpoint in `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.SerializabilityUtil#loadCustomFieldSerializer` to debug the problem.

Comment: Note that all of the CFSs in that changelist implement the static methods, so I'm not sure how that's evidence that it should work. You mean debug in the compiler? Yes I'll try that.

Comment: Oh, looks like `com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc` (not in that change) requires static methods, and those instance methods are only an optimization on the server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Broyer for finding this. It's just a limitation in GWT.

See: `com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.CustomFieldSerializerValidator`

See: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7331&thanks=7331&ts=1335182609